Call function within class
I am trying to write a script that calls the function clear_single_feed_cache() within a class CFF_Feed_Saver_Manager from a wordpress plugin but cannot get it to work. I am not sure if this is because the function I am trying to call has another class within the function. please help. Here is the class and function I am trying to call and below that is my code trying to call that function.
Class & function:
<?php 
 namespace CustomFacebookFeed\Builder;

use CustomFacebookFeed\Admin\Traits\CFF_Feed_Templates_Settings;
use CustomFacebookFeed\SB_Facebook_Data_Encryption;
use CustomFacebookFeed\SB_Facebook_Data_Manager;
use CustomFacebookFeed\CFF_Events_Parser;
   
class CFF_Feed_Saver_Manager {
    use CFF_Feed_Templates_Settings;

public static function hooks() {
            add_action( 'wp_ajax_cff_feed_saver_manager_clear_single_feed_cache', array( 'CustomFacebookFeed\Builder\CFF_Feed_Saver_Manager', 'clear_single_feed_cache' ) );}

    public static function clear_single_feed_cache() {
        $feed_id = '12';
            $feed_cache = new \CustomFacebookFeed\CFF_Cache( $feed_id );
            $feed_cache->clear( 'all' );
            $feed_cache->clear( 'posts' );
    }
    } ?>

My Code:
add_action( 'run_cff_clear_feed', 'myCFFclearFeed');

function myCFFclearFeed() {
   require_once '/var/www/wp-content/plugins/custom-facebook-feed-pro/inc/Builder/CFF_Feed_Saver_Manager.php';
      require_once '/var/www/wp-content/plugins/custom-facebook-feed-pro/inc/CFF_Cache.php';
    $object = new CFF_Feed_Saver_Manager();
$object->clear_single_feed_cache();
                } ?> 


Try using the fully qualified class name: new \CustomFacebookFeed\Builder\CFF_Feed_Saver_Manager()

@ChrisHaas  Thanks just tried that. still not working.

I also now see that the method is static, so it should be called that way, no need for new, just \CustomFacebookFeed\Builder\CFF_Feed_Saver_Manager::clear_single_feed_cache()

@ChrisHaas Yes, That did it! You are the man! Thanks

That's great! Feel free to post what your total solution was an answer.

@ChrisHaas do i post that in the comments? thanks

Thanks @ChrisHaas for figuring it out. The solution was to use the fully qualified class name and since it was a static function the correct code was:
<?php 
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_run_cff_clear_feed', 'myCFFclearFeed');

function myCFFclearFeed() {
   require_once '/var/www/wp-content/plugins/custom-facebook-feed-pro/inc/Builder/CFF_Feed_Saver_Manager.php';
      require_once '/var/www/wp-content/plugins/custom-facebook-feed-pro/inc/CFF_Cache.php';
\CustomFacebookFeed\Builder\CFF_Feed_Saver_Manager::clear_single_feed_cache();
                }
?> 



Just a small thing, and there's a couple of ways to do this, but instead of hard-coding the absolute path to the plugin files, WordPress has some constants that can help you make your code more portable. So I would update your require logic to use something like require_once WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/custom-facebook-feed-pro/inc/Builder/CFF_Feed_Saver_Manager.php'; instead. There's also a function called plugin_dir_path that will get you one step closer.
